# How can use the md-select in the AngularJS ui bootstrap $modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-material

I want to have a Angular material md-select in a angular ui bootstrap $modal.

I'm trying with the following code

**MyController1.js**

```
$modal.open({ 
        templateUrl: My.html,
        controller: MyController2, 
        backdrop: true, 
        windowClass: 'modal'
    });
```

**My.html**

```
<div layout="row">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Items</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedItem" md-selected-text="getSelectedText()">
      <md-optgroup label="items">
        <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in items">Item {{item}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

**MyController2.js**

```
$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
$scope.selectedItem;
$scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    if($scope.selectedItem !== undefined) {
        return "Selected: " + $scope.selectedItem;
    } else {
        return "Please select an item";
    }
};
```

I can view the md-select widget in the modal popup. But If i try to select the value from the "Dropdown" the list is open at the back of the $modal.

**My Edited question: Adding few more things to get exact answer**

I can achieve the same using `md-dialog`. But my code is like this

**MyController2.js**

```
angular.module('myModule', [
])
 .controller('MyController2', ['$mdDialog', '$scope', 
function($mdDialog, $scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    $scope.selectedItem;
    $scope.getSelectedText = function() {
    if($scope.selectedItem !== undefined) {
        return "Selected: " + $scope.selectedItem;
    } else {
        return "Please select an item";
    }
  };
  });
```

So if I have code like the below in **MyController1.js**

```
$mdDialog.show({
  controller: MyController2,
  templateUrl: 'My.html',
  parent: angular.element(document.body),
  // targetEvent: ev,
  clickOutsideToClose:true
})
    .then(function(answer) {
      $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
    }, function() {
      $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
    });
```

It gives me error `Error: MyController2 is not defined`

Comment: you could play with the ``z-index`` css property on the involved elements to fix the problem

Comment: Try this: `controller: 'MyController2'`, to solve the error not defined controller.

Comment: no one solved this issue yet? I have the same problem ang z-index wont help

Answer (score 3):

try this:

.md-select-menu-container {z-index: 9999;}

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to AL Tafas answer, to get the click-away to work you need to add the same to the md-backdrop element.

```
/* Angular Material Overrides */
.md-select-menu-container, md-backdrop {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Add md-backdrop.md-select-backdrop instead of md-backdrop otherwise it will overlay other alerts/toaster

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple **CSS trick** you can overcome this problem

must be greater than your **z-index** of bootstrap popup

```
.md-select-menu-container {
    z-index: 900;
}
```

must be less than the above mention value(900). Otherwise, md-select won't close itself when you click on the background.

```
md-backdrop.md-select-backdrop {
    z-index: 899;
}
```